# Transfer binary file with CANopen

Tags: can-bus, canopen

I would like to transfer a binary file to a CANopen node.
The binary file should finaly written in an Eeprom of the CANopen node.

I'm not sure how I must setup my Object Dictionary for that?

My idea would be to have different objects as manufacturer specific parameters:

- DataIn (array, domain, ... ???)
- Command write
- Status of action

What's the state of the art way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with CANopen but binary transfers I only did with CAN so far.

Checking the CANopen cia 301 documents, I would go with the DOMAIN type, as it fits the problem well:

- *DOMAIN (Object code 2): Large variable amount of data e.g. executable program code.*
- *Domains can be used to transfer an arbitrary large block of data from a client to a server and vice-versa. The
  contents of a data block is application specific.*

The [tutorial](https://canopennode.github.io/md_tutorial_SDO.html) from canopennode has a "Demo domain" part with some examples.

Usually in a CANopen stack you then can react to a received object and start writing to eeprom etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any way how to send the files over CANopen and I am affraid it is not intended for this purpose. If, for any reasons, you need to transfer a file the best approach will be to mount the FS in a senders node, read the file and send the data over SDO service, the block SDO communication fits the best. Look also here
https://youtu.be/GB-a6JRC9WM